# Java Servlet HttpSUrlConnection & sending JSON info securely for webapp & tibco

Tags: java, json, servlets, https, tibco

Ok here's the scenario, i've created a java web application that has a java servlet which is suppose to send a JSON object of all the recorded details to my tibco Integrated Middleware server. I've created the  digital certificates & RSA keys for both servers. The plan is to use the HTTPS protocol to securly send the JSON object from the java servlet to my local tibco server.

My Certificates & RSA keys are in .pem format while my credential file is in .p12 format

[image: As illustrated]

Can someone please enlighten me on how i should write the codes and do the suitable exchange of the credentials for this secure communication? ( Especially on the java servlet end)

I've completely no idea on how i should code the java servlet to build the Https connection with the tibco IM,
I understand that there are java objects like SSLContext,KeyManagerFactory,KeyManager,TrustManager etc but i have got no clue how to use them! Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You invoke HTTPS connection from your servlet to tibco URL, right?

Comment: Yes im trying to send a JSON object through the Https Protocol to my tibco URL

Comment: You have two options: either to use java's URLConnection or jakarta commons httpclient library. If tibco has public authority signed certificate, you do not need to setup certificate trust. If tibco's certificate is self signed then you will need to setup keystore with tibco's certificate and make it trust.